# Read GA4 (Google Analytics 4) sessions via API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Our app has access & refresh token for our customers and we have permissions to read their Google analytics accounts. We noticed that we can not access data of GA4 properties.

I managed to list GA4 properties:

```
GET https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1alpha/accountSummaries
headers: Authorization: Bearer @TOKEN
```

However I can not find a way to retrieve e.g. sessions in last 30 days for GA4 properties (which are returned in the response above). It seems like something like request below should do the trick:

```
POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/{property=properties/*}:runReport
headers: Authorization: Bearer @TOKEN
```

But it doesn't work. What am I missing? Even hints would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `metrics` and `dateRanges` in the body of the `POST` request to `:runReport` method. This is an example [HTTP Post Report Request & Response](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#report_request). This [API Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-cli) discusses specifying the request body in a `request.json`, enabling the Data API, & configuring authentication.

For this report, your request should be similar to the following. `GA4_PROPERTY_ID` should be replaced with your numeric [Google Analytics 4 Property ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/property-id).

```
POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/GA4_PROPERTY_ID:runReport
  {
    "dateRanges": [{ "startDate": "29daysAgo", "endDate": "today" }],
    "metrics": [{ "name": "sessions" }]
  }
```

For this report, the response will be similar to the following:

```
{
  "metricHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "sessions",
      "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "1495"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "rowCount": 1,
  "metadata": {
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "kind": "analyticsData#runReport"
}
```